# Getting NSInvalidArgumentException on iOS 9.0, AFNetworking 2.6.0, XCode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

My app crashes as soon as I initiate http request via AFNetworking. The crash is consistent and returns the following error message:

```
2015-10-02 14:04:40.845 App Name[12130:1274441] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104ddcf65 exceptionPreprocess + 165
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001046f7deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104ddce9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3 Foundation 0x00000001028a429d +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 67
4 App Name 0x0000000101231c28 __28-[LoginController authUser:]_block_invoke + 328
5 App Name 0x0000000101226431 __20+[User login:block:]_block_invoke215 + 113
6 Ap Name 0x00000001012e697b __64-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke_3 + 91
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105575ef9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010559649b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010557e34b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
10 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104d3d3e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE + 9
11 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104cfe939 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
12 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104cfde98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
13 GraphicsServices 0x0000000107d38ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
14 UIKit 0x000000010327b676 UIApplicationMain + 171
15 App Name 0x000000010122d04f main + 111
16 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001055ca92d start + 1)    
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas? Here's the code responsible for the request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] initWithBaseURL:[APIClient BASE_URL]];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[parameters setObject:@"password" forKey:@"user[password]"];
[parameters setObject:@"username" forKey:@"user[username]"];

[manager POST:@"/users/sign_in.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if (block) {
        // Handle response
    }

}   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    block(nil, error, operation);
}];
```

Comment: can you post the code which makes the request

Comment: @matt thanks for your help! I updated the ticket with the failing request. Please note that all of my previously working AFNetworking requests are now failing so it is not related to a particular request.

Comment: @suhit Please see the response above ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question specifies: "iOS 8.0, AFNetworking 2.6.0, XCode 7.0.1". I'm going to guess that that's simply false, and that in fact this is iOS *9*. Networking has completely changed in iOS 9; `http://` requests in iOS 9 are illegal unless you specifically permit them in your *Info.plist*.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Once I updated XCode my SDK switched to iOS 9 and I totally missed that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.